# Casting a function parameter object property in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a function that looks like this:

```
getShopItems: async (parent, { payload }, ctx: Context, info) => { ... }
```

Is there any way to cast the `payload` property of the second argument? I'd like to do something like this, for example:

```
getShopItems: async (parent, { payload: ItemSearchPayload }, ctx: Context, info) => { ... }
```

I'm aware that I can fix this issue by naming the object and casting it to something, a la:

```
interface Args {
  payload: ItemSearchPayload;
}

getShopItems: async (parent, args: Args, ctx: Context, info) => { ... }
```

and in this case I would get typings as expected, but I'm hoping that there's a shortcut because I have a lot of functions like this and I would prefer not to have to create a bunch of interfaces just to use them in one instance like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type destructed parameter inline:

```
getShopItems: async (
    parent,
    { payload }: { payload: ItemSearchPayload },
    ctx: Context, info
) => {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for.

Comment: Another option - adding generic `type Action<TPayload> = { payload:  TPayload }` and then using it as `args: Action<ItemSearchPayload>`